# One @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ACCOUNT OWNER')" works, another very similar - throws SpelEvaluationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, graphql

I have problem with Spring Security and GraphQL.

I have two similar classes:

`UserProfileQuery`:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
class UserProfileQuery implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    private final UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;
    private final AddressRepository addressRepository;

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ACCOUNT_OWNER')")
    public List<UserProfile> getUserProfiles() {
        return userProfileRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ACCOUNT_OWNER')")
    public Optional<UserProfile> getUserProfile(Long id) { return userProfileRepository.findById(id); }

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ACCOUNT_OWNER', 'USER')")
    public Set<Address> getAddresses(Long id) {
        return Optional.of(addressRepository.findByUserId(id)).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(UserProfile.class));
    }

}
```

and `AddressQuery`:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
class AddressQuery implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    private final AddressRepository addressRepository;

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ACCOUNT_OWNER')")
    public List<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addressRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ACCOUNT_OWNER', 'USER')")
    public Address getAddress(Long id) {
        return addressRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(Address.class));
    }

}
```

Both entities, `UserProfile` and `Address` have their own distinct `graphqls` files. Making it short, I'll just post important fragments of those files:

`userprofile.graphqls`:

```
extend type Query {
    userProfiles: [UserProfile]
    addresses(id: ID): [Address]
    userProfile(id: ID): UserProfile
}
```

and `address.graphqls`:

```
extend type Query {
    addresses: [Address]
    address(id: ID): Address
}
```

Now, when I am querying UserProfiles:

```
query {
  userProfiles {
      id
        fullName
    }
  }
```

I get a regular answer (just sample data, don't mind it):

```
{
  "data": {
    "userProfiles": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "fullName": "adgadgd"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "fullName": "adgadgd"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but making similar query on Addresses:

```
query {
  addresses {
      id
        city
    }
  }
```

I get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "addresses": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "extensions": null,
      "message": null,
      "locations": [],
      "errorType": "DataFetchingException",
      "path": null
    }
  ]
}
```

and in the console I get an error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method hasAuthority(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot
```

What am I missing? Both Queries are similar, and only one works...

Comment: Can you try with this @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority({'ACCOUNT_OWNER', 'USER'})")

Comment: nothing changes. the same error. but if it worked, it cannot be accepted cause USER can't have access to the full address list :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it seems that GraphQL doesnt like same names in Query/Mutation methods. In `AddressQuery` I have changed method name from

```
public List<Address> getAddresses()
```

to

```
public List<Address> getAllAddresses() {
```

and propagated this change to `address.graphqls`:

```
extend type Query {
    allAddresses: [Address]
    address(id: ID): Address
}
```

Now the query to get all addresses in `AddressQuery` works like a charm.